# Загрузка\перезагрузка JS скриптов после AJAX перехода на них

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, angularjs

Здравствуйте!
Проблема такова: есть плеер на Angular JS и к нему файл, содержащий информацию о треках (JS конечно).
Если загрузить страницу или перезагрузить ее, то скрипты прогружаются и все работает.
Но стоит перейти на эту же страницу через AJAX, то все перестает работать.
Что делать и как быть?
Вот так загружаю страницы:

```
    function showContent(link,link2) {
    var cont = document.getElementById('content');
    var loading = document.getElementById('loading');
    window.history.replaceState('', 'Title', link2);
    var http = createRequestObject();           
    if( http ) {
        http.open('get', link);                         
        http.onreadystatechange = function () {         
            if(http.readyState == 4) {

                cont.innerHTML = http.responseText;     
            }
        }
        http.send(null);    
    } else {
        document.location = link;   
    }
}
function createRequestObject() {
    try { return new XMLHttpRequest() }
    catch(e) {
        try { return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP') }
        catch(e) {
            try { return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') }
            catch(e) { return null; }
        }
    }
}
```